Update products with custom new stock status import by CSV file
We have an Online Store and we have created (via fuctions.php) a new stock status for "Limited Stock" products. It works completely well and we can also use code to export this data via csv. However, to update the stock status of products or import new products, we use a CSV file.
But, although when exporting it appears in the "In stock?" the correct values, when importing products from "Limited Stock" it does not assume this value but rather "In stock". Can we get it to assume the "limited stock" when importing via CSV?
This is the code we use to "export" the "limited stock" status
function add_custom_stock_csv_data( $_, $product ) {
    $status = $product->get_stock_status( 'edit' );

    switch( $status ) {
        case 'stock_limitado':
            return $status;
        case 'onbackorder':
            return 'backorder';
        case 'instock':
            return 1;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_export_product_column_stock_status', 'add_custom_stock_csv_data', 10, 2 );

